# Putting a left sidebar shading

Tags: beamer

I have a question about beamer. How I can put just a left sidebar shading (also choosing the top and bottom colors)?

I mean, I don´t want to put any text or image in the sidebar.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Which theme are you using for the rest?

Answer (score 1):

You don't give us much information to work with, so this is just a guess:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[left,height=0pt,width=0.12\paperwidth]{sidebar}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=yellow,bottom=blue!50!green] 

\title[]{test}
\author[]{bla}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If horizontal shading is preferred, this has to be entered as `\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[horizontal shading][left=yellow,right=blue!50!green] `

Comment: @user94293 From the phrase "top and bottom colors" I guessed the OP wanted vertical shading, but without more information this is really just a guess.

Comment: Ok, thanks! It does exactly the same!  :)     But could you give me an option to let use also some theme, like Frankfurt, Antibes, Marburg... Better, can be move the Marburg theme's side bar to the left?  :)    Thanks!

Comment: @Jim `\usetheme[left]{Marburg}` instead of `\useoutertheme{...}`

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!   One more question, if you let me  :)       And to put a thin headline, and write upper that headline the section or title the talk?  :)

Comment: @Jim That's not really related to the question you asked. Ask a new question, include a MWE and make a clear sketch how your headline should look like.

Comment: Ok. About this one, now appear the title in the left side bar. I just want the left bar empty, and the title in horizontal, upper the slide. That´s the reason  :)

Comment: @Jim If you look at the code in my answer, I set the title and author so it won't be shown in the sidebar by using `[]`